# How to convert the Parallelogram into a Polygon

Tags: graphics, regions, geometry, conversion

Suppose I have `Parallelogram` like

```
Parallelogram[{1, 2}, {{3, 4}, {6, 3}}]
```

I can convert it into a `Polygon` like this

```
rect = Parallelogram[{1, 2}, {{6, 3}, {3, 4}}];
Graphics[{rect, Red, 
  Polygon@Append[Insert[{#, #} + #2 & @@ rect, First[rect], -2], 
    Total[Last[rect]] + First[rect]]}]
```

It works,but is there a better solution with based method to implement this?By the way I suprise about why `MeshCoordinates[Region@Parallelogram[{1, 2}, {{6, 3}, {3, 4}}]]` don't work, I don't sure it is a bug or intended..

Comment: Why do you need to convert it to a polygon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us take an example from the Help:

```
p = {0, 0};
v1 = {1, 2};
v2 = {1, 0};

ill = {Black, PointSize[Large], Point[p], Arrowheads[Medium], Thick, 
   Arrow[{p, v1}], Arrow[{p, v2}]};
plgm=Parallelogram[p, {v1, v2}];
```

and build a polygon:

```
pol=Polygon[{p, v1, v1 + v2, v2}];
```

Let we have a look:

```
 Row[{Graphics[{Pink, plgm, ill}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 200],
  Graphics[{LightBlue, pol, ill}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 200]}]
```

[image]

In the case of your example one needs also to add the point of origin to coordinates:

```
Graphics[Polygon[{{1,2}, {3, 4} + {1, 2}, {3, 4} + {6, 3} + {1, 2}, {6, 3} + {1, 2}}], 
 Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Strick to my mind..Good example.

Comment: @yode this answer does not conver given Parallelogram to Polygon so I don't understand the accept. (not that I care who gets it, just want the thread to be clear) So if you wanted a basic vector algebra lesson, you should've said so.

Comment: @Kuba  I want to do it in some basic method,so I write that complex solution in my post.And I want to know the behavior is normal or not by `Region@Parallelogram[{1, 2}, {{6, 3}, {3, 4}}]`.I have tried your method in your answer before I post this question.I even remember `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics` will not give right result, but I don't know why I cannot reproduce it now.Actually I hesitate to accept it but it make my thought more clear,and it complete 99% almost.Anyway,you make sense...

Comment: @yode you are free to want whatever you want :) I just claim the accepted answer does not match the question. You can edit the quesion then. Unless I missed the point.

Answer (score 3):

Not each region is a mesh so this is the way to go:

```
prim = Parallelogram[{1, 2}, {{6, 3}, {3, 4}}]

MeshCoordinates @ DiscretizeGraphics @ prim
```

> {{1., 2.}, {7., 5.}, {10., 9.}, {4., 6.}}

You can add `Polygon` of course. And the assumption here is that the mesh will be a single cell one. Don't know if that is a valid assumption but `Parallelogram` should be special for `DiscretizeGraphics` so I guess so.

Alternatively:

```
toPolygon = Apply[Polygon[{#, # + #2, +##, # + #3}] & @@ Join[{#}, #2] &];

toPolygon @ prim
```

> Polygon[{{1, 2}, {4, 6}, {10, 9}, {7, 5}}]

Comment: It is a surprise..I have ever tried `MeshCoordinates@DiscretizeGraphics@prim` and `MeshCoordinates@DiscretizeRegion@prim`，but I cannot guess `MeshCoordinates @ DiscretizeGraphics @ prim` as this need. But they cannot implement it.

Comment: As this [anser](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/154348/21532).I realize the code in above comment  is a typo.So I know what you say before..Actually I want to say I have ever tried `MeshCoordinates@DiscretizeRegion@prim` and `MeshCoordinates@BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@prim`，but I cannot geuss out `**Graphics` something..

Comment: I eventually note this is difference when `**Graphics` work on those object that `RegionQ` will give `False` and `True`.Such as `DiscretizeGraphics /@ {Graphics[Rectangle[]], Rectangle[]}`...

Answer (score 3):

The typesetting system converts a [`Parallelogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Parallelogram) object into a [`PolygonBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolygonBox), so you could use:

```
toPolygon[p_Parallelogram] := Apply[
    Polygon,
    First @ Typeset`MakeBoxes[p, StandardForm, Graphics]
]
```

For your example:

```
toPolygon @ Parallelogram[{1, 2}, {{3, 4}, {6, 3}}]
```

> Polygon[{{1, 2}, {4, 6}, {10, 9}, {7, 5}}]

Answer (score 3):

The 4th example in the Applications section of `RegionEqual` solves a similar problem (see [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionEqual.html#130080454)):

> Find all ways to express the unit rectangle in terms of Parallelogram:

We can adapt the method used there to find all possible 4 vertex polygons:

```
reg = Parallelogram[{1, 2}, {{3, 4}, {6, 3}}];
target = Polygon[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}, {x4, y4}}];

cond = RegionEqual[reg, target];

target /. Solve[cond]
```

> ```
> {Polygon[{{1, 2}, {4, 6}, {10, 9}, {7, 5}}], 
>  Polygon[{{1, 2}, {7, 5}, {10, 9}, {4, 6}}], 
>  Polygon[{{10, 9}, {4, 6}, {1, 2}, {7, 5}}], 
>  Polygon[{{10, 9}, {7, 5}, {1, 2}, {4, 6}}], 
>  Polygon[{{7, 5}, {1, 2}, {4, 6}, {10, 9}}], 
>  Polygon[{{7, 5}, {10, 9}, {4, 6}, {1, 2}}], 
>  Polygon[{{4, 6}, {1, 2}, {7, 5}, {10, 9}}], 
>  Polygon[{{4, 6}, {10, 9}, {7, 5}, {1, 2}}]}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
prim = Parallelogram[{1, 2}, {{3, 4}, {6, 3}}];

MeshPrimitives[DiscretizeGraphics[prim], 2]
```

> {Polygon[{{1., 2.}, {7., 5.}, {10., 9.}, {4., 6.}}]}

```
 % // Graphics
```

[image]

Also:

```
MeshPrimitives[BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[prim], 2] (* or *)
BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[prim]["BoundaryPolygons"]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care duplicated end points:

```
Polygon @@ RegionBoundary[Parallelogram[{1, 2}, {{3, 4}, {6, 3}}]]
```

If you don't want duplicated end points:,

```
Polygon @@ 
 Drop[RegionBoundary[Parallelogram[{1, 2}, {{3, 4}, {6, 3}}]], 
  None, -1]
```